# How do you set a lifecycle policy for an ECR for tagged with any prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I want to set a lifecycle policy for my ECR. For all tagged images to have image count more than 1. 
It's currently set to Prefix and can't set it blank.

**aws ecr policy console:**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible at the moment. The only solution I see is to create an own policy for each of characters [a-zA-Z0-9] so that each of these policies match to tagged images prefixed with that letter. Like this:

```
Policy 1: when tagged and prefixed with "a", expire after 30 days
Policy 2: when tagged and prefixed with "b", expire after 30 days
Policy 3: when tagged and prefixed with "c", expire after 30 days
...
```

Quite insane approach, but it'd work.

To be able to use policy wisely, one should start using some known tag prefixes. For example, one could tag all test images with prefix `test-` and release images with `release-`. Then it'd be sufficient to create policies for just these two prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

Lifecycle policies on all tagged images is [now supported in ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/amazon-ecr-lifecycle-policies-adds-filtering-option-for-tagged-i/)

You can use it by selecting `Any` for "Image Status". Alternatively in JSON, you can create a rule with `"tagStatus": "any"`:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rulePriority": 1,
            "description": "Rule 1",
            "selection": {
                "tagStatus": "any",
                "countType": "imageCountMoreThan",
                "countNumber": 1
            },
            "action": {
                "type": "expire"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No, `"tagStatus": "any"` matches both tagged and untagged images. That rule will remove all but the most recent image, regardless of their tags.

Answer (score -3):

You must put tag prefixes in that field.  If you want, you can search for nearly everything by making a comma-separated list of prefixes, like:

`"a","b","c","d","e","f","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"` ... etc

Comment: According to documentation, all prefixes must match any tag in the image for this to apply, so it wouldn't work. You would need one rule per letter/number, but then you can't use the "more than count" purge option, since they would be counted based on the prefix.